# Python ; IF word in line and word2 not in line

Tags: python, if-statement

Apologies for being a noob here , as i am a newbie in this

i have been trying to write a code which could find a certain words in line and then match from 2nd list of words to see if 2nd word exist in the same line.
only print line only if first word exist not both in a line; here is the snippet and example

```
keywords =("a","b","c","d")
keywords2 = ("e","f","g")
a = ("a  is a ", "a is not e","b is b", "b is not f")
for key2 in keywords2:              
    for key in keywords:                

        for line in a:

                if key2 not in line:
                    if key in line:

                        print(key+" Found in --> ")
                        print      (line)
```

the output required is

```
a is a
b is b
```

while we have

```
a Found in --> 
a  is a 
b Found in --> 
b is b
b Found in --> 
b is not f
a Found in --> 
a  is a 
a Found in --> 
a is not e
b Found in --> 
b is b
a Found in --> 
a  is a 
a Found in --> 
a is not e
b Found in --> 
b is b
b Found in --> 
b is not f
```

i have tried few ways to implement the loop but to no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@joon answers with an answer in the style of your question; here's a couple of other ideas:

Loop over the *lines* first, because the code should work like the question "should I print this line?" for each line.

```
keywords = ("a","b","c","d")
keywords2 = ("e","f","g")

a = ("a  is a ", "a is not e", "b is b", "b is not f")

for line in a:
    for k in keywords:
        if k in line:
            for k2 in keywords2:
                if k2 in line:
                    break
            else:
                print(line)
```

Try online: https://repl.it/CgW8

For/else is a Python idea, but it's a bit weird - if the loop ends normally, `else:` will run and print the line. If the loop breaks, `else:` will not run and will not print the line.

But a more idiomatic answer would be to make use of `any()` which returns True if anything in a list is True, and False otherwise:

```
keywords =("a","b","c","d")
keywords2 = ("e","f","g")
a = ("a  is a ", "a is not e","b is b", "b is not f")

for line in a:
    if any(k in line for k in keywords):
        if not any(k2 in line for k2 in keywords2):
            print(line)
```

Try online: https://repl.it/CgW9

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want only "lines" that have a value from `keywords`, but not `keywords2`. In that case simply do:

```
for line in a:
    if [x for x in keywords if x in line] and not [x for x in keywords2 if x in line]:
        print line
```

`[x for x in keywords if x in line]` loops through all items in `keywords` and adds them to the list if they are in `line`.

`[x for x in keywords2 if x in line]` loops through all items in `keywords2` and adds them to the list if they are in `line`.

An empty list is considered False and you want the `keywords` list to not be empty and the `keywords2` list to be empty.

Comment: Might be more efficient to use `any()`, as this will return on the first `True` value. So use `any(keyword in line for keyword in keywords)`.

Comment: @Andrew Guy - noted and good point. If the lists could be any length using `any` would make a lot more sense...though I suppose you'd have to look out for boolean and None values too.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
keywords =("a","b","c","d")
keywords2 = ("e","f","g")
lines = ("a  is a ", "a is not e","b is b", "b is not f")

for keyword in keywords:
    for line in lines:
        if keyword in line:
            keyword2_exist = False
            for keyword2 in keywords2:
                if keyword2 in line:
                    keyword2_exist = True

            if not keyword2_exist:
                print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could probably work better for you:

```
import re

keywords =("a","b","c","d")
keywords2 = ("e","f","g")

pattern = re.compile(r'^(\w+)\s+is\s+(?:not\s+)?(\w+)')
for line in ("a  is a", "a is not e","b is b", "b is not f"):
    for key1, key2 in pattern.findall(line):
        if key1 in keywords and key2 not in keywords2:
            print (line)
```

From what I understand, there are two keywords in the strings; each in the form `key is [not] key2`, and you are looking to print only those lines where `key` is in `keywords` and `key2` is not in `keywords2`. That is essentially what the above solution does

Answer (score 0):

You should learn some functional programming, Try this:

```
keywords =("a","b","c","d")
keywords2 = ("e","f","g")
a = ("a  is a ", "a is not e","b is b", "b is not f")

for line in a:
    if not any(map(lambda x: x in line, keywords2)):
        if any(map(lambda x: x in line, keywords)):
            print line
```